# Design principles/pattern using repository, data transformation, and math formula

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns

**Update**

I have a RiskReport type, which gets data from IReportRepository, manipulates the data, and calculates risk according to predefined formula.

One might argument that the RiskReport type should get the data in exact format and not perform the data manipulation. RiskReport  should be only concerned with how to calculate data according to formula, Whereas IReportRepository should only return the data required by RiskReport class.

Should a new class be introduced between IReportRepository and RiskReport? Because, currently, the data returned from IReportRepository is manipulated to the required format to calculate the risk.

```
class RiskReport 
{
    private IReportRepository reportRepository;

    public RiskReport(IReportRepository reportRepository)
    {
        this.reportRepository = reportRepository;
    }




    public decimal CalculateDataBasedOnFormula()
    {
        var result = from d in reportRepository.GetReportRelatedData()
                     group d by d.Id into dgp   //potentially complex grouping
                     select new
                                {
                                    TotalPage = dgp.Sum(x=>x.Pages)  //potentially complex projection
                                };


        decimal risk=  //use the result variable to calculate data based on complex formula not shown here

        return risk;

    }
}


interface IReportRepository
{
    IEnumerable<ReportRelatedData> GetReportRelatedData();
}

public class ReportRepository: IReportRepository
{

    public IEnumerable<ReportRelatedData> GetReportRelatedData()
    {
       //return data from underlying data source
        return new BindingList<ReportRelatedData>();
    }
}

public class ReportRelatedData
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public int Pages { get; set; }
    //... more properties here
}
```

Any idea would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is one of those questions where if you ask 1000 devs you could get 1000 answers, but yes, I would say that another class should be used.  Here's my justification:

1. A "math"-ish class could be tested independently
2. A separate class could be reused, keeping the rest of your code DRY
3. If the formulas change, refactoring won't be nestled into your report code

If I had to inherit the code base, I would like to see three classes here, so that's what I would like to leave behind for the next dev if I was developing it.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I changed the Report type to RiskReport type, would it affect your advice?

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Report type, which gets data from IReportRepository, manipulates the data, and
>   calculates rate according to predefined formula.

I think the answer is in your first sentence. If you want the code to be good, make it [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29). "S" stands for Single Responsibility Principle. In other words, if you describe what a class does, don't use the word "and". Change your design accordingly.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer. The three advantages of seperating the concerns mentioned in the awarded post are all a direct consequence of the Single Responsibility Principle.